# POJO to JSON conversion not working for String variable starting with "is"

Tags: java, json, string, mixins

String variable - "isInitial" in below example is not getting converted into JSON. Is it possible to generate JSON structure for **isInitial** variable without modifying the *EmployeePOJO* class?

> PS: converting the getter method to getIsInitial works.

Please find below POJO class used for generating the JSON:

```
public class EmployeePOJO {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String isInitial;
    private boolean isFirstNameAvailable;
    private boolean hasLastNameAvailable;
    private String hasHouse;


    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String isInitial()
    {
        return this.isInitial;
    }

    public void setInitial(String pInitial)
    {
        this.isInitial = pInitial;
    }

    public String getHasHouse() {
        return hasHouse;
    }

    public void setHasHouse(String hasHouse) {
        this.hasHouse = hasHouse;
    }

    public boolean isFirstNameAvailable() {
        return isFirstNameAvailable;
    }

    public void setFirstNameAvailable(boolean firstNameAvailable) {
        isFirstNameAvailable = firstNameAvailable;
    }

    public boolean isHasLastNameAvailable() {
        return hasLastNameAvailable;
    }

    public void setHasLastNameAvailable(boolean hasLastNameAvailable) {
        this.hasLastNameAvailable = hasLastNameAvailable;
    }
}
```

Please find below main logic for POJO conversion:

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.IOException;

public class JacksonPojoToJson {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // Create ObjectMapper
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        EmployeePOJO employeePOJO = new EmployeePOJO();
        employeePOJO.setFirstName("FIRST NAME");
        employeePOJO.setFirstNameAvailable(true);
        employeePOJO.setLastName("last name");
        employeePOJO.setHasLastNameAvailable(true);
        employeePOJO.setInitial("true");

        // Convert object to JSON string
        String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(employeePOJO);
        System.out.println(json);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to change the value of setInitial, maybe add some space like " true", or "true " ?

Comment: What's the expected and current result?

Comment: @AndreiTigau - as per my understanding, setter methods are not called during serialization only getter methods are called.

Comment: @lealceldeiro - I would want the initial value set into the pojo to the part of the JSON. In this case "initial": "true"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Loizos - Thanks a lot for the suggestion **@JsonProperty**, it worked fine. I was looking at a solution without modifying the class - EmployeePOJO (since it is legacy code which we dont want to touch).

I got this resolved by using Mixins, which does not require modification in EmployeePOJO file.

*Sample code which worked for me:*

```
public interface EmployeePOJOMixIn {

    @JsonProperty("isInitial")
    public abstract String isInitial();
}
```

Then adding this Mixin to mapper (*this will vary based on whether you are using fasterxml or codehaus*)

https://www.leveluplunch.com/java/tutorials/024-modifying-fields-external-domain-jackson-mixin/ and https://medium.com/@shankar.ganesh.1234/jackson-mixin-a-simple-guide-to-a-powerful-feature-d984341dc9e2 are good sites which I referred for the solution.

Answer (score 3):

Bad naming conventions. If you are using IDE let the IDE generate the getters and setters for you.

The isInitial method can be used as getter for a Boolean variable. Not a String variable.

So you can fix your POJO class (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_Java_object)

or you can use  the **@JsonProperty** annotation (https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion @JsonProperty, it worked fine. I was looking at a solution without modifying the class - EmployeePOJO. I got this resolved by using Mixins - https://www.leveluplunch.com/java/tutorials/024-modifying-fields-external-domain-jackson-mixin/ and https://medium.com/@shankar.ganesh.1234/jackson-mixin-a-simple-guide-to-a-powerful-feature-d984341dc9e2 are good examples of using it. 
Sample code which worked for me:
public interface EmployeePOJOMixIn {

    @JsonProperty("isInitial")
    public abstract String isInitial();
}

Then adding this Mixin to mapper.

Answer (score 1):

Use Lombok maven dependency for generate automatic getter & setter.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that the `setters`/`getters` for `boolean` variables do not follow the pattern `setVariableName`/`getVariableName`.

You could see in your own code that it is like this:

```
public String isInitial()
{
    return this.isInitial;
}

public void setInitial(String isInitial)
{
    this.isInitial = isInitial;
}
```

Quick fix would be to create the setters/getters for boolean variables manually.
This (setter/getter creation issue) usually happens in eclipse, but I think IntelliJ handles this right.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the correct naming of getters and setters for your variable for example:

> private String isInitial;

For the above variable getter setter should be:

```
public String getIsInitial()
{
    return this.isInitial;
}

public void setIsInitial(String isInitial)
{
    this.isInitial = isInitial;
}
```

Note: I don't know your use case but name like isXXXX used for getters of boolean variables.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Lombok's **@Getter** and **@Setter** annotations to auto-generate your getter and setter methods. Using these, you will not run into issues with naming conventions etc.

Please see the following URL for more information:
https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter